# Install Development Environment CiviCrm for Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I've cloned civicrm-core (4.7.28) and civicrm-drupal (switched to branch 8.x-4.7.28-rc) into my top level modules dir of my Drupal 8.4.
I was able to install dependencies into vendor dir for civicrm-core using composer. I get the following errors when trying to do same for civicrm-drupal:

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - The requested package civicrm/civicrm-core could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

From what I gather the problem is simply a path issue, as civicrm-core 4.7.28 is in a peer dir. As it seems bad practice to modify the composer.json file to point to local path and I wish to keep core/drupal projects in separate dir, there must be a simple solution which I've been unable to stumble on thus far.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Installing CiviCRM on Drupal 8 is still a little dicey due to some Symfony-related issues. See https://www.mydropwizard.com/blog/how-install-civicrm-drupal-8-and-why-choose-it-over-pure-drupal-crm https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17652

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** You can use [this method](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35599/downstream-git-composer-issues/35608#35608) but instead of a version 5.x in the composer command specify dev-master.

You can also use buildkit with e.g. target d8rec-clean. See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8/pull/37

---

**OLDER:**

Here's what I've been doing. I don't think it's the ideal solution and am curious if anyone else has a better way.

1. Use the roundearth installer as normal to install the latest "numbered" version. (https://gitlab.com/roundearth/drupal-civicrm-project)
2. Hack the vendor/roundearth/civicrm-composer-plugin/src/Handler.php file so that:

   (a) getCivicrmCoreVersion() returns 'NIGHTLY'

   (b) addMissingCivicrmFiles() uses `https://download.civicrm.org/latest/civicrm-NIGHTLY-drupal.tar.gz` as the civicrm_archive_url.
3. Delete vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core
4. Run `composer require civicrm/civicrm-core:dev-master civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8:dev-master`