# Downstream Git/Composer Issues

Tags: drupal-8, install, gitlab

I am trying to use the [Drupal 8 Project](https://gitlab.com/roundearth/drupal-civicrm-project) on GitLab and I am having an issue with a downstream CiviCRM requirement. I am not sure where to post this issue, so I hope it is okay if I post it here.

The Composer files download civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin. This asset includes pear/net_smtp. There is also a patch CiviCRM custom error message for CRM-8744.

When Composer attempts to apply the patch, I get the error " Cannot apply patch Add in CiviCRM custom error message for CRM-8744 (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/a6a0ff13d2a155ad962529595dceaef728116f
  96/tools/scripts/composer/patches/net-smtp-patch.patch)!".

I am not sure how to change what files are included in civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin if there should be another patch or how to try and skip the patch in Composer.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: I followed this process and am having a problem where the CiviCRM menu is missing. It looks like the underlying pages may be working if you add the url manually but the menu is not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roundearth just recently switched to using civicrm-asset-plugin and it may not be fully integrated yet.

CiviCRM can be installed on drupal 8 without roundearth now - it's still not "official" but is being used by some.

composer create-project drupal/recommended-project some-folder

cd some-folder

# replace the 'x' below with a proper version number

composer require civicrm/civicrm-core:5.x.x civicrm/civicrm-packages:5.x.x civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8:5.x.x civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin:~1.0.1

Install Drupal as usual

Then to install CiviCRM - make sure the civicrm.settings.php file can be created -> by making the web/sites/default directory writeable:

chmod +w web/sites/default

Then you can either go to Extend and enable CiviCRM Core
or you can do this from the command line:

drush en -y civicrm

Comment: Don't forget to follow that with: :-) composer require 'drupal/webform_civicrm:^5.0'

Comment: He he. That's one way to pad extension usage stats! If you're going to use drush for the rest of the install though then you need to `composer require drush/drush:^8` I think. It didn't work with 9 or 10 the last time I tried but that was a while ago. There are official docs coming, just they aren't up yet.

Comment: I always use whatever Tim decides we should use: which drush -> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/buildkit/bin/drush

Comment: He he. Buildkit is using drush8, but also if you have buildkit installed then you only need one command to do the whole thing: `civibuild create somename --type d8rec-clean`

Comment: No don’t want to do that! That’s too easy :-)

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help.