# roundearth/drupal-civicrm-project fails to give me the CiviCRM menu

Tags: civicrm-home, drupal-8, composer

I now have an automated process working to deploy CiviCRM on drupal based on roundearth/drupal-civicrm-project. Only issue is, `drush en civicrm` fails to expose the CiviCRM menu. What step might I be missing please?

The status page is reporting no errors.  /var/log/apache2/domain.tld-errors.log shows only the server restarts.  No errors in the UI.

But neither is their any CRM menu when I browse to the CRM icon on the drupal menu.  In fact, the browser times out and I am left with a white-screen-o-death.  $drupal_root/vendor/civicrm, includes:

civicrm-asset-plugin
civicrm-core
civicrm-cxn-rpc
civicrm-drupal-8
civicrm-packages
composer-downloads-plugin

composer.json includes:

```
# grep civicrm ../../../composer.json 
    "name": "roundearth/drupal-civicrm-project",
        "civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin": "^1.0",
        "civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8": "^5.24.0",
        "civicrm/civicrm-packages": "^5.24.0",
        "civicrm-asset": {
            "path": "web/libraries/civicrm",
            "url": "/libraries/civicrm"
```

**UPDATE**

Applying the changes recommended by KarinG below, led me to these errors:

```
{{ updated }}
System Status: Error

    Cron Not Running
    Incorrect Resource URL
    Configure Default Mailbox
    Complete Setup
    Old files
```

which led me to run this change:

```
/usr/bin/find files/ -type d -exec /bin/chown www-data: {} \
```

and then browsing to /civicrm, in the logs I am now seeing all these 404's:

```
"GET /modules/contrib/civicrm/icons/ffffff/CiviCRM.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 1738 "http://domain.net/sites/default/files/css/css_G_ErrXTnzvbnVhgrkNAnad6AbqucEyPg7r7hEbARnbY.css
" 
"GET /civicrm HTTP/1.1" 200 10772 "http://domain.net/admin/modules" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 758 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 758 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/bower_components/lodash-compat/lodash.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 760 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 798 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.mousewheel.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 770 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 750 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.form.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 758 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.timeentry.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 768 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.blockUI.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 764 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 798 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/js/Common.js?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 706 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.ui.datepicker.validation.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 798 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/js/crm.datepicker.js?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 722 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/js/crm.ajax.js?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 710 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.tableHeader.js HTTP/1.1" 404 764 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/js/wysiwyg/crm.wysiwyg.js?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 734 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.notify.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 762 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/bower_components/smartmenus/dist/jquery.smartmenus.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 788 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/bower_components/smartmenus/dist/addons/keyboard/jquery.smartmenus.keyboard.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 842 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/js/crm.menubar.js?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 716 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/js/crm.drupal8.js?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 716 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/js/crm.optionEdit.js?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 722 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/js/jquery/jquery.dashboard.js?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 742 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/js/noconflict.js?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 714 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/bower_components/datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 802 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/css/crm-i.css?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 708 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 800 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 782 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 752 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/css/civicrm.css?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 712 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm//bower_components/d3/d3.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 731 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm//bower_components/crossfilter2/crossfilter.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 769 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm//bower_components/dc-2.1.x/dc.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 743 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/css/dashboard.css?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 716 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /sites/default/files/css/css_Z5jMg7P_bjcW9iUzujI7oaechMyxQTUqZhHJ_aYSq04.css HTTP/1.1" 200 554 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /sites/default/files/css/css_nbayFeUgbTUEetzUj2zWWfaIftpVnyzHwC413fE8LR0.css HTTP/1.1" 200 6844 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /sites/default/files/css/css_7yTt9sM3dRkmf7FbAO2SqjGlA2u0qFHoXWeDQTeRulA.css HTTP/1.1" 200 11162 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /core/themes/bartik/logo.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 4044 "http://domain.net/civicrm"
"GET /core/assets/vendor/modernizr/modernizr.min.js?v=3.3.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2406 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 798 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 798 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.ui.datepicker.validation.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 798 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/js/Common.js?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 706 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/js/crm.datepicker.js?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 722 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/js/crm.ajax.js?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 710 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/js/wysiwyg/crm.wysiwyg.js?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 734 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.tableHeader.js HTTP/1.1" 404 764 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.notify.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 762 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/bower_components/smartmenus/dist/jquery.smartmenus.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 788 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/bower_components/smartmenus/dist/addons/keyboard/jquery.smartmenus.keyboard.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 842 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/js/crm.menubar.js?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 716 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/js/crm.optionEdit.js?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 722 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/js/crm.drupal8.js?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 716 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/js/jquery/jquery.dashboard.js?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 742 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/js/noconflict.js?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 714 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/css/crm-i.css?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 708 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 782 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/bower_components/datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 802 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 800 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/css/civicrm.css?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 712 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 752 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm//bower_components/d3/d3.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 731 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm//bower_components/crossfilter2/crossfilter.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 769 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm//bower_components/dc-2.1.x/dc.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 743 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /libraries/civicrm/css/dashboard.css?r=00RaD HTTP/1.1" 404 716 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"POST /contextual/render HTTP/1.1" 200 3751 "http://domain.net/civicrm" 
"GET /core/themes/stable/images/core/icons/bebebe/pencil.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 675 "http://domain.net/sites/default/files/css/css_nbayFeUgbTUEetzUj2zWWfaIftpVnyzHwC413fE8LR0.css"
```

**UPDATE #2**

Thanks again, KarinG.  That project does not seem to be working for me at the moment.  Any guidance?

```
~/sandbox $ composer create-project drupal/recommended-project my_client_crm
Creating a "drupal/recommended-project" project at "./my_client_crm"
The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
```

Comment: When I browse directly to the /admin/configtask?reset=1 path, I get expected content less the .js and .css.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like perhaps you’re missing ->

https://gitlab.com/roundearth/drupal-civicrm-project/-/issues/2

But I do recommend you change how you install D8/CiviCRM to as described in here:
[Downstream Git/Composer Issues](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35599/downstream-git-composer-issues)

Answer (score 0):

my weeks-long missing civicrm-menu and related issues has finally been resolved through the creation of symlinks.  This article provided some guidance:
https://colorfield.be/blog/install-civicrm-5-with-drupal-8-using-lando

Studying the 404 errors in the network tab of `inspect element` provided clues.  The use of  mlocate identified appropriate targets for the links.

The symlinks got created in a new path, called web/libraries/civicrm, and now include: ang, bower_components, core, css, js, packages.

Not completely sure that all of those links are necessary, but I have higher priorities than sorting out if I can live without any of these.

The results looks like this:

```
root@efc9c26-00257:/opt/local/path_to/drupal/web/libraries/civicrm# ls -lht
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 May 28 19:52 bower_components -> ../../../vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/bower_components                                                                               
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 May 28 19:50 ang -> ../../../vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/ang
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 May 28 19:44 core -> ../../../vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 May 28 19:42 packages -> ../../../vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 May 28 19:42 css -> ../../../vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/css
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 May 28 19:42 js -> ../../../vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/js
```

Nothing I did to set the ResourceURL, either in the browser UI (crippled by the absence of its javascript libraries) or in civicrm.settings.php seemed to help much.

Comment: The reason for /web/libraries/civicrm being a separate copy of just the needed web-asset files is because it's a security risk to have all the vendor files be available under /web. If you're missing stuff under /web/libraries it's because somehow civicrm-asset-plugin didn't get triggered to do its thing. Roundearth only recently switched to using that and it may not be fully working. As KarinG notes I'd also suggest using the other install method. There's no official docs yet but they're in the works.

Comment: Thanks, Demerit, I will watch for that documentation for the next iteration on my deploy process.  I now have a seemingly stable build.  Took me 144 builds on my CI server to get here.  Until it seem broken again, I'm inclined to pull the next user story off the board.  Ten of my last twenty deployments have run without error, resulting in mostly working installations.  Those build failures and not-quite working successful builds, have been unrelated to this issue.  

Priority right now is getting civimail to work.  More on that in another question, coming soon to StackExchange.